# Bit-Mapped Memory Manager

Tags: c++, memory-management

I am reading a tutorial on writing memory management tools for c++ programs. Here is the [link](https://developer.ibm.com/tutorials/au-memorymanager/) to the tutorial.

One of the variants of this memory manager is a Bit-Mapped Memory Manager in which optimization is based on the idea of prefetching a large chunk of memory and using it in our programs later. 
This chunk is further divided into smaller fixed-sized units called blocks to be used for the allocation of a particular type of object.

The tutorial clearly mentions, "All free blocks have their corresponding bit set to 1. Occupied blocks have their bits reset to 0."

With each chunk, a bitmap is associated which represents the above idea. But, in the implementation of BitMap class, each corresponding bit for each block is represented by a 32-bit integer instead of just a single bit boolean value. This is what I am not able to understand.

Also, below is the declaration of the above-mentioned class. You can see this in the Listing-12 of the tutorial. I also think the line with memset is incorrect. The initialization is incomplete and it should be BIT_MAP_SIZE*4 even if we go their way.

```
typedef struct BitMapEntry
{
  int Index;
  int BlocksAvailable;
  int BitMap[BIT_MAP_SIZE];

  public:
    BitMapEntry(): BlocksAvailable(BIT_MAP_SIZE)
    {
      memset(BitMap, 0xff, BIT_MAP_SIZE / sizeof(char)); 
      // initially all blocks are free and bit value 1 in the map denotes 
      // available block
    }

    void SetBit(int position, bool flag);
    void SetMultipleBits(int position, bool flag, int count);
    void SetRangeOfInt(int* element, int msb, int lsb, bool flag);

    Complex* FirstFreeBlock(size_t size);
    Complex* ComplexObjectAddress(int pos);

    void* Head();
}
BitMapEntry;
```

Comment: I'm reading this tutorial too and I think the implementation is wrong, especially `ComplexObjectAddress` method, which return the same address to `Complex` object multi times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The initialization does seem to be incorrect, but the choice of a "bit container" type as `int` is not necessarily invalid.

You see, C++ doesn't have a native bit type; and on typical computers - you can't address single bits.

What could be happening (and you haven't shown use the implementation), since that each `int` can be the container for `sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT` bits, thus if you ask for position `k`, you'll be looking at the `k % (sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT)` in the `k / sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT)` integer.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how using int can still be valid? Also, if we are looking at k%32 bit in the k/32 integer, are we not using the other 31 bits for any good reason? Also, which implementation would you like to see?

Comment: We're using all 32 bits of each it (assuming it's 32 bits; which isn't always the case by the way). The bit at position `k` is `BitMap[k / (sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT)] >> (k % (sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT)) & 0x1`.

Comment: I understand the mathematics above but what I mean to ask is, "What purpose are those 32-bits serving instead of just one?".

Comment: @PiyushKansal: 1. You can't have "just one" - neither in terms of the language, nor in terms of the common hardware. 2. There's a minor alignment benefit when copying and initializing.

Comment: I understand it now. Thanks for your kind help.

Comment: @PiyushKansal: The way to thank me is accept the answer and possibly upvote it.